# table -- is mutating, trigger/function may not see it error in oracle sql 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to create auto incrementing ID in my table which should have substrings and is padded.

In order to do that, i created a sequence, function and a trigger as follows:

```
create sequence account_number_seq
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NOCACHE;

create or replace function reginfo_func
return varchar2
is sub varchar2(20);
begin
    select SUBSTR(Account_Type,1,2) || SUBSTR(FirstName,1,3) || RPAD(Account_Number_seq.nextval,10,'0')
    INTO sub from registeredinfo;
    return sub;
end;

create or replace trigger reginfo_trig
before insert on registeredinfo
for each row
begin
if (:new.account_number is null) then
:new.account_number := reginfo_func;
end if;
end;
```

When inserting/copying data from a table to this table, i'm experiencing this error:
The account number should be generated automatically.

```
ORA-04091: table CASESTDY.REGISTEREDINFO is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "CASESTDY.REGINFO_FUNC", line 5
ORA-06512: at "CASESTDY.REGINFO_TRIG", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'CASESTDY.REGINFO_TRIG'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think its because SUBSTR(Account_Type,1,2) || SUBSTR(FirstName,1,3)  are from another table... can I declare this as a variable as select statement in my function?

Answer (score 3):

This is because in your function you are trying to SELECT from the table you are modifying.
You don't actually need the function, just change your trigger to be:

```sql
create or replace trigger reginfo_trig
before insert on registeredinfo
for each row
begin
if (:new.account_number is null) then
:new.account_number := SUBSTR(:new.Account_Type,1,2) || SUBSTR(:new.FirstName,1,3) || RPAD(Account_Number_seq.nextval,10,'0');
end if;
end;
```